# Gradle pass commandline arguments to subproject run task

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following project-structure:

```
Root project 'rmi-tutorial'
+--- Project ':client'
+--- Project ':lib'
\--- Project ':server'
```

How can I pass command line arguments via the root-project run task to another certain sub project?

I thought about something like this:

```
gradlew.bat run -Pclient:<parameter1> -Pclient:<parameter2>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the project properties are still available in the `project.properties` map.  Should you wish to access them from any level of your project, you may do so.